# Axios render get data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, fetch, axios

How can I render a get response, for example in 3 divs (firstname,lastname), try to do this for several days and nothing happens
I did it on jquery, but now I need to react

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

import axios from 'axios';

class Table extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios
        .get('http://server.noorsoft.ru:9022/api/records')
        .then(({ data })=> {
            this.setState({
                data: data.data
            });
        })
}

render() {
    const getDataRender = // here render div //
        return <div>
        </div>
    });

    return <div>
        <div>{ getDataRender }</div>
    </div>;
}

class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Table />
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

It will be great if you describe in detail what my mistake is

Comment: I would recommend to just compile it first without the errors. To give some insight, your render method is the main error-prone part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
axios.get('http://server.noorsoft.ru:9022/api/records')
        .then(({ data })=> {
            this.setState({
                data: data
            });
        })
```

You destructure data already, so you don't need to do `data.data`, instead, just data.
Inside of render method, if you just want to render the data array, you can just do:

```
render() {
  return(
   <div>
    {this.state.data.map(record => <div>{record.firstName+' '+record.lastName}</div>)}
   </div>
  )
}
```